# Adding fractions calculation not working in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nslog

I am trying to add fractions to get a value to put in for my progress bar but am just getting 0. here is what I have and what it is logging.

```
 NSLog(@"prog::%f",self.progView.progress);
    int total = self.forms.count;
   float calc =  (float)(self.progView.progress / total) + (1/total);
    NSLog(@"calc::%f",calc);
    NSLog(@"total::%d",total);
    self.progView.progress = calc;
    NSLog(@"prog now:%f", self.progView.progress);
```

Log:

```
prog::0.000000
calc::0.000000
total::4
prog now:0.000000
```

Comment: The progress is simply "current count / total count" assuming "current count" will start at 0 and go to "total count". This gives a value in the range 0.0 to 1.0. The current progress should not be part of the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care of where you place your cast to float. Try changing from this:

```
float calc =  (float)(self.progView.progress / total) + (1/total);
```

To this:

```
float calc =  ((float)self.progView.progress / (float)total) + (1/(float)total);
```

Alternatively, make `total` a float rather than an `int`, e.g.

```
float total = self.forms.count;
float calc =  ((float)self.progView.progress / total) + (1 / total);
```

Comment: hmm that seems to help but I think my math is wrong or something.. I am expecting (for this example) the progress bar to go up by .25 every time and its goes from .25 to 0.312500 to  to 0.332031 Why?